# How to use shortopts in getopt() in pyhton

Tags: python-3.x, getopts

I'm having trouble understanding the meaning of semi-colons in shortops. I have such a longopt `["help", "runNum=","allplots=","sys=","redblue=","signalinj=","ranking="]` and I assign values to parameters with

```
try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],"h:", ["help","runNum=","allplots=","sys=","redblue=","signalinj=","ranking="])
except getopt.GetoptError:
    print("Bad option. ")
    sys.exit(2)

for o, a in opts:
    if o=="-h" or o=='--help':
        print("Ex: python3 app.py --runNum=55 --allplots=1 --sys=1 --ranking=0 --redblue=0 --signalinj=0")
    elif o=="--runNum":
        runNum = 'r'+str(a)
    elif o=='--allplots':
        _allplots=a
    elif o=='--sys':
        _sysflag=a
    elif o=='--ranking':
        _ranking=a
    elif o=='--redblue':
        _redblueflag=a
    elif o=='--signalinj':
        _signal_inj=a
```

When I run the app with `python3 app.py` without any shotopts, it works fine but running with `-` option returns `"Bad option"` error instead of `"Ex: python3 app.y ..."` and `--help` returns `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'runNum' referenced before assignment` error. So how can I make it print `"Ex: python3 app.y ..."`.

I also tried `"h:o"` but no improvement. This semi colon usage is still a mystery to me. i appreciate it if someone can explain this and tell me what to put on shortopts.

Comment: The "runNum" error happens because you are missing a double quote on the second line.  Note that your code block above is not colored correctly because of that.

Comment: `-h` doesn't work because you have `"h:"`.  The "colon" means that the -h parameter must have an argument.  Change that to `"h"`.

Comment: I'm sorry but the missing " is just a copy paste error. I have it in my original code. I did try with `"h"` as you said but this time I got the same `UnboundLocalError`